# how to host a asmx web service on iis

Tags: web-services

Hi Can anyone please advise me on how to host an asmx webservice build in .net 3.5 on IIS6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no different than hosting a website.  Copy the site to the root of the web server (or any desired subfolder thereof), configure the folder as an application in IIS (right click, Properties, Create Application or something of that nature), ensure the .NET 2.0 runtime is selected.

Is there a specific problem you're encountering?